# gitlab-ci: always run late stage and take failed/success from earlier stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following stages in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test-azure
  - test-after-analysis
```

If `test-azure` fails `test-after-analysis` is skipped unless I add the
`allow_failure: true` then it continues but success is set based on `test-after-analysis` stage which always is true. (just gather metrics and logs from internal systems about the test-azure tests done).

How can I always run the `test-after-analysis` stage and let the pipeline output the `test-azure` status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `allow_failure:` on jobs in the `test-azure` stage, set `when: always` on the jobs in the `test-after-analysis` stage.

`when: always` will ensure the job runs irrespective of the status of jobs in the previous stage -- even if the jobs don't have `allow_failure:` set.